# How to debug a WCF service that hosted by Windows Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I host my WCF Service with windows service hosting...
now when I call my service I cant debug it!Can I debug my service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run VS in administrative mode
2. From Debug menu choose attach to process...
3. Choose your service process
4. Put a breakpoint in your service

Comment: Whow. Do that 100 times a day while you develop the service and you just wasted half the day reinstalling.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition, consider NOT hosting it in a windows SERVICE during development. Whenever I have a service, I have an alterantive code path to start it as a command line program (if possibly with an /interactive command line parameter etc.) so that I do not ahve to deal with the specifics of Service debugging (need to stop to replace assemblies etc.).

I only turn to "Service" for deployment etc. Debugging is always done in non-service-mode.

Comment: +1.  All my service code goes in a service class, which I can then run from within a console app and debug just fine.

Comment: Actually I have a special wrapper taht uses the service class and "manually" starts the service. ;) But the concept is the same. Debugging services as service is a PAIN.

Answer (score 0):

[Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) Worked for me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a walkthrough [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/how-to-debug-a-wcf-service-hosted-in-windows-service/).
It suggests adding two methods OnDebugMode_Start and OnDebugMode_Stop to the service (actually exposing OnStart and OnStop protected methods), so the Service1 class would be like this:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    ServiceHost _host;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Type serviceType = typeof(MyWcfService.Service1);
        _host = new ServiceHost(serviceType);
        _host.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _host.Close();
    }

    public void OnDebugMode_Start()
    {
         OnStart(null);
    }

     public void OnDebugMode_Stop()
     {
         OnStop();
     }
}
```

and start it in program like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
#if DEBUG
        // Run as interactive exe in debug mode to allow easy debugging. 

        var service = new Service1();
        service.OnDebugMode_Start();
        // Sleep the main thread indefinitely while the service code runs in OnStart() 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        service.OnDebugMode_Stop();
#else
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                           { 
                                     new Service1() 
                           };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Configure service in app.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyWcfService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="MyWcfService.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWcfService/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata  httpGetEnabled="True"  policyVersion="Policy15"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

You're all set.